# How to count occurrences with unique columns and rows in SQL?

Tags: mysql, performance

This question is very similar to :https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1503959/edit
But I want to take it one step further, and create new columns for each age, with a count for that age.

I have a table of people:

```
name  | age
--------
bill  | 25
tom   | 25
tom   | 23
tom   | 23
```

I want to query for all names, and additional columns that counts how many names are of the same age:

```
name  | 23 | 25
----------------
bill  | 0  | 1
tom   | 2  | 1
```

What's the most efficient way of doing this? **I fear that a sub-query will be slow, and I'm wondering if there's a better way**. Is there?

Comment: Why do you want ages as columns, not rows?

Comment: I want a report of how many people with names are of different ages, it will make the table much smaller by making it 3 dimensional.

Comment: Actually the table will be much shorter. but the size might actually be much larger, if there are a lot of values where there are people not of the age.

Comment: that's not how SQL works. You life will be much easier if you use 2d tables in SQL. It's possible to do what you want, using dynamic SQL and stuff, just painful and pointless.

Comment: The problem is doing this with a table of 100 different ages and 100 different people is more painful to do by hand using 2d tables and then changing it to 3d tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have many age values,dynamic pivot is very useful

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when age = ''',
      age,
      ''' then 1 else 0 end) AS ','`',
      age,'`'
    ) ORDER BY age
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  t;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT name, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM t 
                   GROUP BY name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea913/6)

Comment: I think this just shows 1 or 0 when the age appears.. I would like the number to reflect the number of times the age of the person is, duplicate rows can exist.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way how to do this in SQL is using `GROUP BY`.

`SELECT name, age, COUNT(*) AS occurence
FROM table
GROUP BY name, age`

But you get data in different format. You need to reformat them in PHP, because SQL doesn't work way you want.

Comment: I know this is a possibility. In SQL I can do it, the query will just get large and ugly

Comment: It's not about large and ugly query. It's about speed. MySQL isn't good with subqueries, nor group_concat and you wanted most efficient way. So I tell you that most efficient way is use simple GROUP BY query a reformat result in PHP, which is way much faster.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I wanted to just use SQL and what was most efficient in SQL.